# Conjuncting : Is this valid word

Tags: meaning, word-usage, continuous

I am trying to write one sentence like this

`I will display Employee Code and Employee name by conjuncting hypen. (EMPCODE-EMPLOYEENAME)`

I noticed that the word `Conjuncting` is wrong in MS-WORD where it is accepting `conjunct` as valid word.

Then what is the corresponding continuous word for `Conjunct`.

How I can re-frame my sentence with same meaning.

Appreciate your prompt response on this.

Comment: Try to give an example of your new sentence. You need to think too.

Comment: Thanks :) Gave the sample sentence in questions itself. Formatted now

Comment: Ok. Your welcome.

Comment: *Conjoin* is the verb corresponding to *conjunct*, but in this case I don't recommend using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "conjunct" is not commonly used as a verb if it can be at all. I would recommend a more common term like "concatenate." The way I would change your sentence to use "concatenate" is as follows:

> I will display the the Employee Code and Employee name by concatenating them with a hypen. (e.g. EMPCODE-EMPLOYEENAME).

Better yet, simplify the sentence this way:

> I will display the Employee Code and Employee name as EMPCODE-EMPLOYEENAME.

Answer (score -1):

"To concantenate" is not only wrong but totally awkward, at the very least indecorous. 
There are dozens of words that the English language offers in such a sentence. "Integrate"  is but one. "Embrace," "connect," "accomodate," "assimilate," "incorporate," and many, many more are available.

"Conjuncting" and "concatenating" are quite a few pages beyond the Oxford Dictionary.

Comment: You have several remaining typos: "concantenate" is not spelled correctly in its first appearance (and isn't spelled the way the other answer had it), and "accomodate" isn't spelled right at all. You should explain why each word should (or should not) be used and in what circumstances.